# Vuejs3 How to add a class when clicked

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

trying to do something like addclass using style binding to translate jQuery syntax for vue. I tried a way to run a style class that was created beforehand when a button is clicked in a vue template.I tried to imitate the on and off function with the function used with v-if and v-show, but it failed to use.

this jquery

```
  $('.menu_btn').click(function(){
      $('.mo_gnb').toggleClass('on')
      $('.menu_btn').toggleClass('on')
      $('body').toggleClass('on')
      $('.sidebar-overlay').toggleClass('on')
  })
```

```
<template>
  <template>
      <button
        class="menu_btn"
        :class="{'menu_btn' : open }"
        @click="open">
        <span class="line"></span>
      </button>
      <nav
      v-if="openshow"
      :class="{ 'mo_gnb.on' : open }"
      class="mo_gnb">
      <ul
        v-if="!username == '' "
        class="tnb cursor">
        <li
          class="user_name">  
          <p><span>{{ username }}</p>
        </li>
        <li @click="remove()">
          로그아웃
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <router-link
            to="/Home_en"
            class="on">
            Dantaro Service
          </router-link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <router-link to="/Guide_en">
            User Guide
          </router-link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <router-link to="/Intro_en">
            Introduce
          </router-link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <router-link to="/service_center/notice">
            Service Center
          </router-link>
        </li>
        <div class="lang_wrap">
          <li class="lang_btn">
            <router-link to="/Home">
              KOR
            </router-link>
          </li>
          <li class="lang_btn">
            <router-link
              to="/Home_en"
              class="on">
              ENG
            </router-link>
          </li>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div> 
  <div
    class="sidebar-overlay"
    :class="{ 'sidebar-overlay' : open }"></div>
  </template>
</template>
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const openshow = ref(false)
function open() {
  openshow.value = !openshow.value
 }
</script>
```

Comment: The jquery code toggles the class `on` on several elements, whereas, your code does not do anything with those elements - and `:class="{ 'mo_gnb.on' : open }" class="mo_gnb"` doesn't make any sense at all - you probably want `:class="{ 'mo_gnb': true, 'on' : open }"` - and where ever you have `class="on"` use `:class={on: open}`